# filterring GAE logs

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

Is there a way for me to filter Google App Engine logs to show log entries that contain two strings in them e.g. both "hello" and "world" ?

or alternatively can I search for log entries of requests to a specific path that contain some string?

Comment: Do you mean through the Developer Console or using the [Logs API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/#Java_Getting_log_data)?  You can also automatically export your logs to Big Query (click **Exports** at the top of the developer console log viewer).

Comment: I was referring to the Developer console, and I don't see an "Exports" option in the log viewer.